# Incremental reports with JasperReports

Tags: sql-server, database, jasper-reports, reporting

I am using *JasperReports* to generate reports from *SQL Server* on daily basis. The problem is that every day the report reads data from beginning, but I want it to exclude records read earlier and include only new rows. The database is old and doesn't have timestamp columns in table so there is no way to identify which records are 'new' and which ones are 'old'. 
I am not allowed to modify it either.

Please suggest any other way if possible.

Comment: You can try to use *INSERT* trigger - it can allow you to write info about new records

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table and every time you print records on your report, insert that records in the table. So you can use a query with a **NOT EXISTS** condition from the original table on the new table.
The obvious drawbacks of this approach is space consumption on the DB and the extra work needed in inserting records on the new table, but if you cannot modify the original table, it's the only solution. 
Otherwise the Alex K suggestion is very good.